# Disabling answer ban by editing old answers

Tags: support, feature-request

I got a answer ban for I used different language in SE. I believe that I some edit these. This ban will disabled as automatic by my forum contributions. I have 9 point :/. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: The edits you refer to was someone using Google Translate to make your answer intelligible to English readers, and then someone else reversed that, since Google Translate isn’t reliable enough for philosophical discourse.

Comment: By using another dictionary, the problem is solved as much as possible.